# Multiple mysql_connect statements canceling each other out

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database-connection, chat

I am trying to code an ajax chat application using php and my sql. I have a file called connect.php that looks like this:

```
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database name");
```

I have another file called Core.php that needs this same connection to the database in order to get the chat messages from my database. Core.php looks like this:

```
class Core {
protected $db, $result;
private $rows;

public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password','database name') or die('Connection Failure');
}
}
```

How do I set $this->db to the same connection I already have open?

As it is right now connect.php is called in my init.php file before Core.php and results in the chat messages not showing up in the box. If I comment out the call for connect.php then the chat messages display but all of the users login data can't be accessed and the user gets logged out. Can anyone help me with this? It's driving me crazy

EDIT: This is my init.php file where core.php and connect.php are called

```
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

$current_file = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file = end($current_file);

require 'core/database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'classes/Core.php';
```

Comment: Those are two different api. Don't mix them.

Comment: well i realize mysql and mysqli are different but the tutorial video from phpacademy codes it that way. is there a way to change my connect.php file to access my database through mysqli?

Comment: You already have a connection in db property. Use that. I don't see why you need the that connection file at all. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because the core.php file is only being used for the chat. the connect .php was for all my other pages before i coded this.

Comment: how do i use that mysqli statement as my database connection. when i call that instead of connect.php it says no database selected

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated.  You should use the mysqli_ functions.  Also, where do $host, $u, $p and $db get defined?  Shouldn't you be passing those things to your constructor?

Comment: yeah i'm currently in the process on trying to figure out how i can switch over to mysqli since my whole site is coded in mysql. My $host, $u, $p, and $db values are defined right where they are in the code above I just didnt want to post the actual names. I guess I should have made it clear that the only variable are the ones declared at the top of Core.php

Comment: Yeah, you shouldnt have used $db as the db name in place of the real name because it's just confusing as you dont pass anything in, and $this->db is the top $db :p

Comment: How are you reading the connect.php into the Class Core to be able to reuse the connection?  You need to `extends` the Class or use an `include`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing so this is best guess answer... For one, how are you assigning the already open connection?

```
//connect.php
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$u", "$p");
    mysql_select_db("$db");
?>

<?php
include 'connect.php';

class Core
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        global $conn;
        $this->conn =& $conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I updated my post with the code for my init.php file so idk if that will help.

Comment: I also tried this but it doesnt quite work. now the users don't get logged out when they go to the chat page but if they refresh it they do.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Why do the users have to be logged out to go to the chat page?  I think your question needs a little more explanation, maybe even draw a process flow diagram so we can see how you would like things to work. Then show us what code you have for each section.

Comment: Haha. I meant I want them to be logged in. The problem was with the fact that they only stayed logged in when I went to the page the first time. if they refreshed it for some reason then they would be logged out and I didn't want that. I've come to the conclusion that I just need to recode my site in mysqli and then I will be able to fix this problem.

Comment: Ok - but i think it's more your process than which library you are using.  You should be able to pretty much create a chat feature to any account logged in whether mysql or mysqli... it would require someone looking at more than just the code you provided in this question though to solve your problem I think.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me troubleshoot this Christian. I actually converted everything over to mysqli and an OOP format and now my chat feature works just like I want it to. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new mysqli('$host', '$u', '$p','$db') or die('Connection Failure');
 }
```

this code will not run, be sure u have used "$host"/"$u"..etc instead of '$host' or '$u'

php parser will parse it as a string not a variable inside the quotation.

Comment: I made a mistake with sharing the code earlier. Those values are not variables. That code works as long as I comment out  the call for connect.php